# Issue with List threshold limit exceed and choice fields

Tags: sharepoint

I have a Sharepoint list with 12000 items, I am querying that list with choice field has (filter) and the resulted items are 10100, but I am getting the error below.

The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator. Operations that exceed the list view threshold are allowed in the following time window defined by the administrator.

I know it is because of max threshold limit and resource throttling limit set in central admin.

The question is if I remove the filter it will retrieve all 12000 items.
I tried with indexing choice field as well, but I still get the same error.

Below is my code:

```
                     List tList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("tests");
                   ListItemCollectionPosition titemPosition = null;
                    ListItemCollection tcollListItem;
                    CamlQuery tquery = new CamlQuery();
            while (true)
                 {
                  tquery.ViewXml = "<View Scope='Recursive'><Query><Where><Eq>
                 <FieldRef Name='tType' /><Value Type='Choice'>first</Value>
                 </Eq></Where></Query> <RowLimit>500</Rowlimit></View>";

                    tquery.ListItemCollectionPosition = titemPosition;
                    tcollListItem = tList.GetItems(tquery);
                    clientContext.Load(tcollListItem);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    titemPosition = tcollListItem.ListItemCollectionPosition;

                    if (titemPosition == null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                }
```